# call method from other class (self issue)

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, object, self

I would really like to know the proper solution to this problem…if in MyOtherClass I need to call a method in MyMainClass for example I know how:

```
MyMainClass *class = [MyMainClass alloc] init];
[class runSomeMethod];
```

The problem is if in runSomeMethod I refer to self it is a different self because it is a different instance called from MyOtherClass. I understand this (and know how to workaround it), but please someone educate me on what is the right way to handle this and call the original instance of MyMainClass if need be. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to call a method on your object that's already been instantiated, why not store it in an instance variable or property so you can refer to it later?

Comment: Do you have object of MyOtherClass in MyMainClass?

Comment: @AaronBrager Yes that's basically what I was doing.

Comment: @ParagBafna No. What I'm getting at is what Aaron said I want to access the object that's already been instantiated, not a new one.

Comment: What is connection between MyMainClass and MyOtherClass?

Comment: @rick, Aaron Brager is not suggesting you to create new MyMainClass object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an instance of your own class, you can use the `self` object to call that method.

Then when you refer to `self` in your method, you will be using the same instance.

So, you should call your method as

```
[self runSomeMethod];
```

Alternatively, if you want your class to refer to one object at all times, you may want to consider creating your class as a singleton class, i.e., no matter what - your class will always issue one object.

**SINGLETON WAY**

To create a singleton class, go to your `MyMainClass.h` and add this property:

```
+ (MyMainClass *)singletonInstance;
```

Then in your implementation file, `MyMainClass.m` add in the following code:

```
//Just below @implementation MyMainClass
static MyMainClass* _singletonInstance = nil;

+(MyMainClass*)singletonInstance
{
@synchronized([MyMainClass class])
{
    if (!_singletonInstance)
        _singletonInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    return _singletonInstance;
}

return nil;
}


+(id)alloc
{
@synchronized([MyMainClass class])
{
    NSAssert(_singletonInstance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
    _singletonInstance = [super alloc];
    return _singletonInstance;
}

return nil;
}
```

That is it. Now whenever you want to call `MyMainClass`'s object, just use `[[MyMainClass singletonInstance] runSomeMethod]`.
Also, when you use `self` now, it will refer to the same object.

Comment: I understand this but how can I call self from another class? And I might have to look into making a singleton class I actually don't know how to do that. :-)

Comment: Have updated my answer above. Would appreciate if you marked it correct.