# Calling method from another class doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, iphone, class, methods, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to change the text and the position of a UILabel from another class.

I have successfully managed to call my -changeLabel method, which is in my FirstViewController class, from my SecondViewController class. Here is the code I have used in my two classes:

SecondViewController:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize firstViewController;

- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [firstViewController changeLabel];
}
```

FirstViewController:

```
- (void)changeLabel {
    NSLog(@"changeLabel is called!");
    label.text = @"New text.";
    label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, 150, 40);
    NSLog(@"%@", label.text);
    NSLog(@"%f", label.frame.size.width);
}
```

The weird thing is that the logger looks like this after pressing the "button" that calls the method:

```
"2013-12-30 19:24:50.303 MyApp[655:70b] changeLabel is called!"
"2013-12-30 19:24:50.305 MyApp[655:70b] New text."
"2013-12-30 19:24:50.308 MyApp[655:70b] 0.000000"
```

So it seems the label text change, but it doesn't show up on the screen. And the label width is logged as 0.0.. even though I just set it to 150.

Why is this happening? Am I not able to change frame variables from another class? Is there another way to do this?

IMPORTANT:

As the `FirstViewController` is the main view controller while the `SecondViewController` is a side menu, similar to the facebook app:

[image]

I want to be able to press a "button" on the `SecondViewController`(side menu) and call a method in the `FirstViewController`(main) that changes the position(frame) of a `UILabel`.

EDIT:

Here is how I created the UILabel:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40);
label.text = @"Text."
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout ?

Comment: How do you create the `label`?

Comment: Most probably `FirstViewController`'s view is not loaded.

Comment: The label I refer to is created programmatically, so no, I'm not using autolayout.

Comment: @Peter: in which method you are creating the label ?

Comment: In the -viewDidLoad method. So the FirstViewController's view is loaded as far as I understand.

Comment: try to add `firstViewController.view;` after `firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: @Hani Ibrahim: That didn't help, and I don't understand why that should help. All it did was giving me a warning and made the application stop when pressing the button.

Comment: As you said that you initialize the label in `ViewDidLoad` ... However the `ViewDidLoad` is not called until the view is loaded in memory ... So I suggested that you can do any hack (not a good one but just trying) to load the view by trying to access it to get it loaded ... Did the app crash? ... if so can you put a break point in viewdidload and see where is crash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to do this thanks to "@Gaurav Wadhwani" answer on this question: [call method from other class (self issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823557/call-method-from-other-class-self-issue).

I added this code in my `FirstViewController.h`:

```
+ (FirstViewController *)singletonInstance;
```

And then added this code in my `FirstViewController.m`

```
static FirstViewController  *_singletonInstance = nil;


+(FirstViewController*)singletonInstance
{
    @synchronized([FirstViewController class])
    {
        if (!_singletonInstance)
            _singletonInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        return _singletonInstance;
    }

    return nil;
}


+(id)alloc
{
    @synchronized([FirstViewController class])
    {
        NSAssert(_singletonInstance == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _singletonInstance = [super alloc];
        return _singletonInstance;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then I added this code in my `SecondViewController` to run the `changeLabel` method:

```
[[FirstViewController singletonInstance] changeLabel];
```

And that seems to work just fine so far. I hope it wont cause any other "problems" in the future, but right now it seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is this. You are calling method from new instance of `FirstViewController`.

Let assume

```
1. FirstViewController at stack[0].
2. SecondViewController at stack[1].
```

If you are navigating or moving from

`FirstViewController->SecondViewController`

In this case `FirstViewController` already in memory with some address `0x23ffff`.

And in `SecondViewController` you are again creating new instance of `FirstViewController` which is point to another address '0x234jurhu`

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [firstViewController changeLabel];
}
```

Don't create new instance here.

You can use `delegate` or `NSNotification` concept for this.

Comment: You are correct about moving from First->Second ViewController. But how can I call the method without creating a new instance of FirstViewController?

Comment: @Peter I mentioned, you can use `delegate` concept or `NSNotification`.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to do it using delegate concept?

Comment: You can my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259159/unable-to-pushviewcontroller-after-dismissing-present-view-controller/20259386#20259386

Answer (score 1):

How are you displaying `FirstViewController`?

Here is the issue:

```
firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[firstViewController changeLabel];
```

You creating a new instance of `FirstViewController` and updating the label text. If your using these VC's in a navigation stack and you pop back to FirstViewController from `SecondViewController`, you won't see any label change because `they` are different instances of the class.

If your using `FirstViewController` as a childViewController of `SecondViewController` (with naming of them I don't think this what your doing), then in the `- (IBAction)button:(id)sender`  method you don't need to instantiate a new instance of FirstViewController on each button press.

Comment: This seems pretty legit, but what do you suggest to make it work? How can I call the -changeLabel method from the SecondViewController without creating a new instance of FirstViewController?

Comment: That comes into how your stack is constructed. Are you using a navigation controller to push views?

Comment: @Peter I just saw your edit, I will need to see how you are managing the two view controllers. How are they layered? Does SecondViewController manage the FirstViewController? What is the code that handles the opening and closing?

Comment: The havent written the code that navigates between the two view controllers myself. I followed this tutorial to create the slide menu: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/. But when switching back and forth between the two view controllers no "loading" method is called, by that I mean -viewDidLoad, -viewWillAppear: and similar methods is never called. Only the first time opening up the application. If you understand what I mean. :)

Comment: I understand this problem might be very complex, but I hope you still follow along ;)

Comment: @Peter I'm not very good with Storyboard, I don't use them. But what you'll need to do is reference FirstViewController through SWRevealViewController's frontViewController property. I downloaded the examples from the git repo and can make it work fine on ones not using Storyboards.

Answer (score -2):

Try doing this:

```
[label setNeedsDisplay];
```

After the last line in `changeLabel`.